# Best GIT strategy for a project overhaul

Tags: git

I have an existing GIT project that I am going to significantly overhaul. I think the easiest strategy will be to start with a blank slate and copy/paste the pieces I need over from the existing project.

Knowing that, my plan was to create a new empty (orphan) branch in my existing repo and then eventually promote it up to the 'master' branch.

But thinking through that, I don't want it to try to merge the new branch with any of the existing branches because things are going to get messy.

Would it be better to create a whole new repo in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to say you should go with the orphan branch, because:

1. Most git projects aren't about just the code, there is documentation on wikis, issues on issue trackers and other metadata that is associated with the repository on github/bitbucket/gitlab etc. A new repo means you loose the continuity on those front as well.
2. While new repo offers a clean slate allows for under the radar kind of development, referring any of the development history is not possible if you don't have the older codebase - you may loose information in git commit messages, and perspectives on coding choices that commits can encapsulate.
3. Branch names in git are nothing but labels on commit ids, and it is easy to just move your branches around. For example, in future, you can create an archived branch of your master branch, and push the orphaned branch as master, doing away with the need of merging the branches:

   ```
   git push origin master:master_archive
   git push origin orphaned_branch:master -f
   ```

So, in essence, use a new repo if a combination of below is true for you:

a. your codebase is smallish (there is not much context to be lost)

b. very few devs work on the project (not much knowledge transfer required)

c. you want to fly under the radar

d. you plan on discarding all the older code and tickets and references in future.

e. your wikis and bug tracking are not coupled with the repository

Comment: mhm you list the advantages of a fork but decide for an orphan?

Comment: @David a fork is as good as having a replica of the original repo, you don't loose any of the commits or branches or tags the original repo had. So, IMO, fork is a bad idea here - it doesn't add any value in the newly created repo - and neither does it help with the tickets or so on.  Either you create a new repo, or you use an orphan branch. Also, IIRC, github doesn't allow same user to fork the repo twice.

Comment: yeah you might be right, most attractive reason you mentioned is "flying under the radar" ;-), sure if she has all the old code by herself anyway she never needs the old stuff in the new repo perhaps and in the end the new orphan looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

An empty branch isn't really empty of code... it just contains no modifications. I would say the simplest solution is a new repository. However ask yourself what your goals are for the git repository – is it A) just redundancy or is B) the edit history important?

If the answer is A then definitely use a new repository. If it's B then you need a new branch and you're going to have to deal with the merge. The merge doesn't have to be difficult – you just always select `use mine` for merge conflicts.

Comment: "An empty branch isn't really empty of code... it just contains no modifications" - Sorry, but that's wrong. Because it depends on what "empty" refers to. The branches you are thinking of are not empty, they point to some commit that's already been pointed to by something else. A truly empty branch starts at the same place as a new repo: With an empty tree and no parent commits. I'm currently not sure how it's created, but it's definitely possible. The only difference to a new repo would be, that other branches exist within the same repo that do not share any history with the empty one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just fork the original repo and start from there.
Even if you replace every file you still have the old reference in older versions available.
You can improve some overview perhaps with Tags or branches.

Edit: also the reference to the forked repo is always existing (on github as a link) and it might be useful still to visit that in future too.